# How can I find the file that emit this error?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass

When I run my react app with npm start to face this error. I'm using node : v14.17.6 & npm: 6.14.9 .
Is it about sass loader? My sass loader version is ^12.1.0

```
./src/index.scss
(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
        
Error: Can't resolve './fonts/themify.eot' in 'H:\react-admin\multikarthtmnl-321\all_in_one_multikart_react\back-end\src'
```

```
index.scss path : src/index.scss
app.scss : src/assets/scss/app.scss
themify.eot path : src/assets/fonts/themify.eot
```

```
index.scss content :
@import 'assets/scss/app.scss';
@font-face {
    font-family: "Vazir";
    src: local("Vazir"), url("./assets/fonts/Vazir.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
 app.scss :
@import 'bootstrap.scss';
@import 'theme/variables';
@import 'theme/admin_style';
@import 'theme/rtl';
@import 'flag-icon.scss';
@import 'themify.scss';
@import 'icoicon/icons';
@import 'font-awesome.scss';

.rootFont {
    font-family: "Vazir";
}
```

Comment: Could you please prove your code for the batter idea? It's something related to `./fonts/themify.eot` failed to load font.

Comment: The themify.eot is in : src/assets/fonts/themify.eot . I added content of index.scss in question